# Building a simple compiler with OCaml

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, ocaml

I've spent a day trying to a simple compiler program but still have difficulties understanding this function.

```
let rec expression tokens = 
  let (trm, tokens') = term tokens in
```

here so (trm, tokens') is a tuple, is term a function or a variable? How can a tuple = two variables or a function

```
  expTail trm tokens'

and
  expTail trm tokens = 
  match tokens with
    Tokenizer.PlusTok::tokens' ->
      let (trm', tokens'') = term tokens' in expTail (Plus(trm, trm')) tokens''

  | Tokenizer.MinusTok::tokens' ->
      let (trm', tokens'') = term tokens' in expTail (Minus(trm, trm')) tokens''

  |  _ -> (trm, tokens)
```

what does this line mean? it doesn't seem to call anything. And why is it now (trm, tokens) not (trm', tokens'')

```
and
  term tokens = let (trm, tokens') = factor tokens in termTail trm tokens'
```

Not really sure what this line means either.

```
and
  termTail trm tokens =
  match tokens with
    Tokenizer.TimesTok::tokens' -> 
      let (trm', tokens'') = factor tokens' in termTail (Times(trm, trm')) tokens''

  | Tokenizer.DivTok::tokens' -> 
      let (trm', tokens'') = factor tokens' in termTail (Div(trm, trm')) tokens''

  | Tokenizer.ModTok::tokens' -> 
      let (trm', tokens'') = factor tokens' in termTail (Mod(trm, trm')) tokens''

  | _ -> (trm, tokens)

and
  factor tokens =
  match tokens with
  Tokenizer.LParenTok::tokens' -> 
  let (expr, tokens'') = expression tokens' in
      (match tokens'' with
      Tokenizer.RParenTok::tokens''' -> (expr, tokens''')
  | _ -> raise (Syntax "Bad factor, failed to find )\n")) 

  | (Tokenizer.IntTok i)::tokens' -> (Bits i,  tokens')

  | _ -> raise (Syntax ("Bad factor."))
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are pretty basic questions. It might be good to start with an OCaml tutorial (maybe see previous SO question [OCaml Resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073436/ocaml-resources)).

Some answers:

```
let (trm, tokens') = term tokens
```

This calls a function named `term` passing `tokens` as the argument.  The result is a pair.  You're going to refer to the first element of the pair by the name `trm` and the second by the name `tokens'`.

```
and
   term tokens = let (trm, tokens') = factor tokens in termTail trm tokens'
```

These are the lines that define the `term` function called above.

```
  |  _ -> (trm, tokens)
```

This is the default case for the pattern match.  If neither of the other two patterns matches, the value is given by this alternative.  This is basically a value, not a function call.  However, in some sense there is a function involved--you're *constructing* a pair.  The comma (`,`) is used as nice syntax for constructing a pair.  (The parentheses are actually optional, though stylistically I like to see them.)

The names `tokens` and `tokens'` are just different names.  There's no inherent relation between them.  In this default case, no value named `tokens'` is defined.  So it's not possible to refer to such a value here.  Conventionally, adding a "prime" to the end of a name is used to indicate that the new value is somehow derived from the old one.